# Can goats talk?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

The Goats in Putting Your Hoof Down are clearly [sentient](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15357/3804), but they don't speak. Are they able to talk or are they just quiet?

Comment: My theory is that they speak a different language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say given that the only major occurence of them we've seen is in Putting Your Hoof Down. Given that they wear microphones, it's logical to guess that they were just casted as background characters for Iron Will and do in fact have the ability to talk.