# If the ponies are vegetarian, why do they raise pigs?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

From everything I've seen so far, the ponies seem to be herbivores. We never see them eat meat products of any kind. But the Apple family raises *pigs* in their farm (Season 3 Episode 10 "Spike at Your Service"). It makes sense for ponies to raise sheep (for the wool), cows (for the milk) and chickens (for the eggs), but why would they need to raise pigs if they don't eat meat?

Comment: They could sell the pigs to carnivores.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but pretty damn close; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15357/are-only-hoofed-creatures-sentient

Comment: @Richard - never noticed that bit in the end. You're right. This question may very well be a dupe.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to [Lauren Faust](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Lauren_Faust), creator, writer and Senior Animator of "Friendship is Magic", the [pigs](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Animals) were kept for humanitarian (pigitarian? ponitarian?) reasons as well as to help the ponies to locate truffles.

[image: Lauren Faust webchat]

Obviously it can't be for food, given that ponies in Equestria are

> ***strictly vegetarian***

Answer (score 37):

### Equestrian ponies are not exclusively herbivores.

[image]

That looks like a meat sandwich to me, and Pinkie Pie references hot dogs in *Fall Weather Friends*.

One could argue that they're vegetarian equivalents, but that just pushes the notion back to "equivalent of *what*?" The presence of a vegetarian hot dog implies an original meat hot dog for it to be mimicking.

Equestrian ponies aren't like real-world ponies in many ways. Being omnivores is one of these differences.

(It doesn't seem that they eat a *lot* of meat. Faust's justification of pigs as truffle-hunters is probably also true, perhaps even primarily true, but it probably isn't the entire truth. Please note, even in an unofficial off-the-cuff answer Faust didn't indicate that ponies don't eat meat).

Comment: There;s also an exclamation from Applejack about "Pork chops and apple sauce" in Micro-Series comic book issue #2, when lightning from the cloud gremlins' cloud strikes a tree near her.

Comment: @Richard Ah, but are the comics canon? (Correct answer: [mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)); 'canon' is a worthless concept)

Comment: FiM canon is like Doctor Who canon: something the fans argue about and the creators ignore.

Comment: "Equestrian ponies aren't like real-world ponies in many ways. Being omnivores is one of these differences." -- Note, real-world horses _can and do_ eat meat on occasion, even of their own volition (as opposed to an owner feeding it to them). See, for example, [Deadly Equines: The Shocking True Story of Meat-Eating and Murderous Horses](http://www.amazon.com/Deadly-Equines-Shocking-Meat-Eating-Murderous/dp/1590480031). (That said, a horse's digestive system is not designed for meat and a high-meat diet for an extended period is not going to end well for the horse.)

Comment: @evilsoup, I have no intention of being the world's foremost authority on MLP:FIM canonicity :-P

Comment: @Richard and here I thought I'd found the Chosen One at last. Ah well, back to the road.

Comment: @BESW - The canon now contains this lovely song explicitly confirming that the ponies in Equestria are **strictly vegetarian**; http://youtu.be/gKVNI9jeFK4?t=54s. Unfortunately, that makes this answer 100% wrong.

Comment: There are meat eaters in Equestria, like the birds in S1E07. Non-magic animals seem to be equivalent of their Earthly counterparts, and Capper probably eats fish.

Answer (score 8):

The ponies are shown several times baking and cooking various meals and dishes. Some of these require some kind of fatty substances that could be pig lard.
They also wear clothes sometimes, for which they could use pig leather. Pig hooves can be used to fabricate buttons that can also be used to make dresses.

Comment: Same with cows. I haven't noticed any animal graveyards, so perhaps they consume the dead.

Answer (score 5):

What are pig farms used for? To dispose of the bodies! (see [Snatch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0208092/) and [True Blood](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0844441/), for example)

In this context, as [previously mentioned](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48040/if-the-ponies-are-vegetarian-why-do-they-raise-pigs#comments-48059), no graveyards - so where do the corpses go?

Comment: A less morbid reason, all those rotten, cored, or cider apple leftovers need to be disposed of somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what non-pork uses are there for raising pigs.

**Truffles!!!**

Plowing/land clearing

Fertilizer

Boar's hair for brushes

Waste products can be used to generate electricity

Comment: All good uses, but aside from the quote above in my answer, is there any proof that they're actually used for these purposes?

Comment: How do you use a pig for plowing?

Comment: @Oldcat Pigs naturally scavenge under the soil for roots and grubs.  As they nose the ground they inevitably dig leaving behind a nicely aerated soil devoid of old roots